# Merge csv and xlm files and inject in to PGSQL with Azure Data Factory

Tags: postgresql, azure

Since a weeks I'm strugeling with a task. I have few csv files with some data and xlm file witch contains some metadata.
I need to import data from csv in to Posgresql DB, which is not a problem, I know how to do that. But during this import or just after that, whatever, I need to get some metadata from xml and join it with each line from csv.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

+

```
<Document>
    <meta1>something</meta1>
    <meta2>Somethingelse</meta2>
</Document>
```

===

| Column A | Column B | meta1 | meta2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | something | somethingelse2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | something | somethingelse2 |

I was trying to use Data Factory, pipelines. Also Dataflow with a join function but this doesn't work for me, in join function I need to set join conditions and I don't know how. Maybe I should use some expresion, and what type of join should be used?
Also I know that join function can not be used with PGSQL as a sink. I need to use something else like json, CosmosDB, SQL DB or REST.

Not mention taht I need to build universal solution for various similar packages located in many Blob Storage Containers. But for now I need to merge data.

Would be appreciate for any sugestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you are trying to combine the xml (1 row) with csv (multiple rows) such that each of the csv's rows have corresponding XML row values, using cross join in dataflows might help in achieving the requirement.
- I have taken the sample csv and xml data as 2 sources in my dataflow. The following is an image of the xml data that I have.

[image]

- I have created 2 separate columns for `meta1` and `meta2` from the `Document` column (complex type) using derived column transformation.

[image]

- Then I used `select` transformation to select only two columns and not `document` column.

[image]

- Now, use join transformation, select cross join with join condition as `true()`.

[image]

- Also choose broadcast options () in `optimize tab` as shown below:

[image]

- Then, when you use data preview, you can see the data as per the requirement.

[image]